# How to subscribe for APNs with an application without security enabled?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight 6.0.0.1

I have an application without security and I want to enable it to subscribe to APNs notifications.

The main reason for not to have security is because I want to be able to start the application without connectivity. Later, if the device gets connectivity it will subscribe.

When the application starts it asks for a userId, so I have a user id. But I have not found the way to use that userId in the APNs subscription.

Is it possible to manually set the user for the subscription?

I have tried just to test and WL.Client.Push.subscribe fails somehow, onSuccess or onFailure callbacks are never executed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

UserId is mandatory for push notification. The reason is simple - you want to know who exactly you're sending this notification to. So having an authenticated user is mandatory requirement for subscribing to a push notification. In case you don't really have security you still need to implement authentication. However credentials validation can be dummy. The easiest way to implement it would be via adapter authentication. Just collect userId and use WL.Server.setActiveUser() API without validating it. Once you have your active user set - subscription will be functional.

Comment: Ok, is there any way I could programatically create and set the credentials using client api without any server interaction?
I understand that what is really needed is the device token, the user id is an internal key Worklight uses for getting that device token when I want to send a notification, I mean I think it is not mandatory for APN but it is for Worklight. A way to workaround this would be nice.

Comment: Thinkig again about this I think it can be possible to make the login transparent to the customer so instead of ask the user for username and password the application logins in the background with the corresponding "user" as a topic instead of a username and then register the device for notifications. This way with the security I do a registration not an identification.